# Can I name GNU screen sessions?

Tags: linux, gnu-screen, gnu

I use multiple sessions for different things. One for work, one for school work and one each project I'm working on. It gets really hard to keep track of the sessions when `screen -ls` returns

```
11292.pts-0.chu (09/12/11 14:13:49)     (Detached)
7616.pts-4.chu  (09/01/11 10:31:57)     (Detached)
1834.pts-0.chu  (08/31/11 18:32:16)     (Detached)
1810.pts-0.chu  (08/31/11 18:45:20)     (Detached)
```

Is there any way I can name my sessions for better control?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you create new session, you can use `screen -S <mysession>`

In already running session, hit `Ctrl-a` and type `:sessionname <mysession>`

Comment: Your answer was better than mine

Answer (score 6):

Read the documentation more thoroughly. It seems once I'm in a session I can name it using

```
screen -S <name>
```

Comment: don't forget the `-t` option, too - allows you to "title" the session, so in addition to a name (say, "www-dev"), you can see in your PuTTY (or similar) title bar something like `"CSS reconfiguration"`